# Image picker flutter web 1.9

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Looking for image picker on new flutter web 1.9. I found a way but for less than 1.9, now that is merged dont know how can i achived this. Tried with dart:html but is not working on release! Only on running

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like as for `Flutter web 1.10 dev` , [universal_html package](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) is good candidate for the temporarily vacant position of `dart:html`:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/prefer_universal/html.dart' as html;

class ImagePickerLabPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImagePickerLabPageState createState() => _ImagePickerLabPageState();
}

class _ImagePickerLabPageState extends State<ImagePickerLabPage> {
  String name = '';
  String error;
  Uint8List data;

  pickImage() {
    final html.InputElement input = html.document.createElement('input');
    input
      ..type = 'file'
      ..accept = 'image/*';

    input.onChange.listen((e) {
      if (input.files.isEmpty) return;
      final reader = html.FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataUrl(input.files[0]);
      reader.onError.listen((err) => setState(() {
            error = err.toString();
          }));
      reader.onLoad.first.then((res) {
        final encoded = reader.result as String;
        // remove data:image/*;base64 preambule
        final stripped =
            encoded.replaceFirst(RegExp(r'data:image/[^;]+;base64,'), '');

        setState(() {
          name = input.files[0].name;
          data = base64.decode(stripped);
          error = null;
        });
      });
    });

    input.click();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(name),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.open_in_browser),
        onPressed: () {
          pickImage();
        },
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: error != null
            ? Text(error)
            : data != null ? Image.memory(data) : Text('No data...'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working fine, but how can we keep it's type as Image? I just wanna upload it to firebase, but it's not uploading as Image.

Comment: html.InputReader and html.FileReader not importing successfully showing error there. Can you please let us know how to solve it?

Comment: @Umair Make sure that you specified correct [package](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) in `pubspec.yaml`, and no other packages in your code imported with `html`-alias.

Comment: Compiler message:
lib/main.dart:240:5: Error: Factory redirects to class 'FileReader', which is abstract and can't be instantiated.
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

Comment: @Umair You can create a new question. Show int it your `pubspec.yaml` and code from `lib/main.dart` file

Comment: The solution that worked for me that i have changed my channel and make sure to use only that package in that code. Thankyou for your solutions

Answer (score 4):

Actually onChange doesn't work well on mobile safari, it need to change addEventListener and also need to append it.

```
Future<void> _setImage() async {
    final completer = Completer<List<String>>();
    InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
    uploadInput.multiple = true;
    uploadInput.accept = 'image/*';
    uploadInput.click();
    // onChange doesn't work on mobile safari
    uploadInput.addEventListener('change', (e) async {
        // read file content as dataURL
        final files = uploadInput.files;
        Iterable<Future<String>> resultsFutures = files.map((file) {
            final reader = FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
            reader.onError.listen((error) => completer.completeError(error));
            return reader.onLoad.first.then((_) => reader.result as String);
        });

        final results = await Future.wait(resultsFutures);
        completer.complete(results);
    });
    // need to append on mobile safari
    document.body.append(uploadInput);
    final List<String> images = await completer.future;
    setState(() {
        _uploadedImages = images;
    });
    uploadInput.remove();
}
```

**This also works:**

```
Future<void> _setImage() async {   
    final completer = Completer<List<String>>();
    final InputElement input = document.createElement('input');
    input
      ..type = 'file'
      ..multiple = true
      ..accept = 'image/*';
    input.click();
    // onChange doesn't work on mobile safari
    input.addEventListener('change', (e) async {
      final List<File> files = input.files;
      Iterable<Future<String>> resultsFutures = files.map((file) {
        final reader = FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
        reader.onError.listen((error) => completer.completeError(error));
        return reader.onLoad.first.then((_) => reader.result as String);
      });
      final results = await Future.wait(resultsFutures);
      completer.complete(results);
    });
    // need to append on mobile safari
    document.body.append(input);
    // input.click(); can be here
    final List<String> images = await completer.future;
    setState(() {
      _uploadedImages = images;
    });
    input.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bulkin, it really help!!

Comment: @Bulkin Thank you! saved me as image_picker_web has conflicts with iOS ( for device I use image_picker) and my app runs both on web and device.

Comment: holy moly. you are my hero. How on earth did you figure this out? I figured that on mobile web the flutter code was somehow backgrounded during file selection... but I was totally lost on what to change. I need to understand your document.append better

Answer (score 2):

why don't you just use: https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_web

It supports also multiple outputTypes (File, Widget, Uint8List)

Comment: I tried this, doesn't work, gives an unknown type on location. If somebody gets it to work, ket me know. It an issue in the package "issues"

Comment: but it supports only for web