# Why returning value from picked file is null ? Flutter

Tags: html, flutter

In my App I'm using image_picker and image_picker_web but it throws `No podspec found for 'image_picker_web' in '.symlinks/plugins/image_picker_web/ios'`exception when running on iOS.
So I decided not to use it and pick the file like in the accepted solution here  [How to Pick files and Images for upload with flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56252856/how-to-pick-files-and-images-for-upload-with-flutter-web?rq=1).
Print for picked file is correct but my method returns null a I guess it returns the variable before it gets assigned a value.
I don't know html so I'm kinda lost here..
What am I doing wrong with returning the picked value?

```
FileReader reader = FileReader();
InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();


Future<Uint8List> pickImage() async {
    print('FirebaseImageStorageRepositoryWeb. pickImage() started');
    // image_picker_web works on web but creates pod problems on iOS

//    Uint8List imageData;
//    String fileName;
//    await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery).then((picked) {
//      picked.readAsBytes().then((data) {
//        imageData = data;
//      });
//    });

    // image_picker // notworking on web...

    

    //html
    Uint8List imageData;
    InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement();
    uploadInput.click();

    uploadInput.onChange.listen((e)  {
      // read file content as dataURL
      final files = uploadInput.files;
      if (files.length == 1) {
        final file = files[0];

        print(
            'selected file: type:${file.type},name: ${file.name}, size: ${file.size}');

        reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
          imageData = reader.result;
//          return imageData; // not working
        });

        reader.onError.listen((fileEvent) {
          print('Some Error occured while reading the file');
        });

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      }
    });
    return imageData;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the answer at [Image picker flutter web 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043499/image-picker-flutter-web-1-9) (not the accepted one .. ) I could see what was wrong with the code above..

## working:

```
@override
  Future<Uint8List> pickImage() async {
    print('FirebaseImageStorageRepositoryWeb.pickImage() started');
    final completer = Completer<Uint8List>();
    final InputElement input = document.createElement('input');
    input
      ..type = 'file'
      ..multiple = true
      ..accept = 'image/*';
    input.click();
    // onChange doesn't work on mobile safari
    input.addEventListener('change', (e) async {
      final List<File> files = input.files;
      Iterable<Future<Uint8List>> resultsFutures = files.map((file) {
        final reader = FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files.first); // .readAsDataUrl(file);
        reader.onError.listen((error) => completer.completeError(error));
        return reader.onLoad.first.then((_) => reader.result);
      });

      final results = await Future.wait(resultsFutures);
      completer.complete(results.first);
    });
    // need to append on mobile safari
    document.body.append(input);
    // input.click(); can be here
    final Uint8List image = await completer.future;
    input.remove();
    return image;
  }
```